# Finding complex limit

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\left( {{x^2} {\cos
>  ^2}x -  {\sin ^2}x} \right)\left( {{x^3} - {\sin ^3}x}
>  \right)}}{{{{\left( {{e^x} + {e^{-x}} - {x^2} - 2} \right)}^2} \sin
>  x}}$$

I don't know what to do here... (Everything can be used, apart from integrals and Taylor expansions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, divide top and bottom by $x^9$.
You have four unrelated limits:
$$\lim\frac{x^2\cos^2x-\sin^2x}{x^4}\\
\lim\frac{x^3-\sin^3x}{x^5}\\
\lim\frac{e^x+e^{-x}-x^2-2}{x^4}\\
\lim\frac{\sin x}x$$
Can you use L'Hopital?
Use the Limit Laws to turn 
$$\lim\frac{AB}{C^2D}=\frac{(\lim A)(\lim B)}{(\lim C)(\lim C)(\lim D)}$$
which is fine so long as each piece has a non-zero limit.

Comment: How can I do the second limit quickly? I have tried 4 DLH and it gets more and more difficult to compute, because of the messy algebra.

Comment: Try to turn $\sin^3x$ into $\sin x$ and $\sin 3x$